# Kubernetes persistent volume on own rack

Tags: kubernetes, block-storage

I move kubernetes from Google GKE to own in house rack. What persistent storage should I use?

Kubernetes Local Persistent became beta in 13th of April 2018 only
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/

I have seen that many options:-
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes

Not sure what should I choose. Will something work out box with GKE deployment files?

Answer (score 3):

In Deployment files from GKE, you need to change `spec.volumes` settings according to your Persistent Volume setups.

I recommend you to choose one of the following options:

1. The easiest way is to use `HostPath`. It mounts a file or a directory from the host Node’s file system into your Pod. Note that in this case, data on one Node is not reachable from another Node without additional configurations. Example of usage in Kubernetes:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: test-pd
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
       name: test-container
       volumeMounts:
       - mountPath: /test-pd
         name: test-volume
     volumes:
     - name: test-volume
       hostPath:
         # directory location on host
         path: /data
         # this field is optional
         type: Directory
   ```
2. You can use `NFS`. You need to configure NFS server and after that you can use its volumes in Deployments via Persistent Volume Claims. Example of usage in Kubernetes:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: nfs-busybox
   spec:
     replicas: 2
     selector:
       name: nfs-busybox
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           name: nfs-busybox
       spec:
         containers:
        - image: busybox
           command:
             - sh
             - -c
             - 'while true; do date > /mnt/index.html; hostname >> /mnt/index.html; sleep $(($RANDOM % 5 + 5)); done'
           imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
           name: busybox
           volumeMounts:
             # name must match the volume name below
             - name: nfs
               mountPath: "/mnt"
         volumes:
         - name: nfs
           persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: nfs
   ```

   You can look through the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs) for more information about using NFS.
3. You can use `GlusterFS`. You need to configure your own GlusterFS installation, and after that you can use its volumes in Deployments. Example of usage in Kubernetes:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: nfs-busybox
   spec:
     replicas: 2
     selector:
       name: nfs-busybox
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           name: nfs-busybox
       spec:
         containers:
        - image: busybox
           command:
             - sh
             - -c
             - 'while true; do date > /mnt/index.html; hostname >> /mnt/index.html; sleep $(($RANDOM % 5 + 5)); done'
           imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
           name: busybox
           volumeMounts:
             # name must match the volume name below
             - name: nfs
               mountPath: "/mnt"
         volumes:
         - name: glusterfsvol
           glusterfs:
             endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
               path: kube_vol
               readOnly: true
   ```

   You can look through the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/glusterfs) for more information about using GlusterFS.

You can find more information about Persistent Volumes and Persistent Volume Claims [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims).